# C# joined lists. LINQ. unable to create a constant type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asynchronous

imagine the following method.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
    {

        List<PageVirtualServer> pageVirtualServer = await context.PageVirtualServer
              .Where(z => z.StatusPageId == id)
              .ToListAsync();


        List<StatusMessage> messages = await context.StatusMessages
              .Where(x => pageVirtualServer.Any(
                         y => y.VirtualServerId == x.VirtualServerId))
              .ToListAsync();

        return  Ok(messages);
    }
```

The following exception occurs..
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'xy'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

But when embed the first query into the second - it does work,
I don't get it.

Why does this method work but the first doesn't ?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
    {

        List<StatusMessage> messages = await context.StatusMessages
             .Where(x => 
                context.PageVirtualServer
                   .Where(z => z.StatusPageId == id)
                   .Any(y => y.VirtualServerId == x.VirtualServerId))
             .ToListAsync();

        return  Ok(messages);
}
```

Can someone explain this behaviour ?

Comment: Doesn't `ToListAsync` return you a `Task<List<object>>`, instead of `List<object>`? You'd have to unwrap the `result`

Comment: Even without the async and await. EF throws me a "notsupportedexception" :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, you materialize a list of `PageVirtualServer` objects in memory, and you pass that list of (complex) objects to the second query. Linq to Entities can not translate this into SQL.

In the second query, you essentially tell EF to use the table `context.PageVirtualServer` resulting in EF generating a SQL query to perform the whole operation at once.

To perform such an operation in two steps, you could materialize the ID's in the first query:

```
        List<int> pageVirtualServerIDs = await context.PageVirtualServer
              .Where(z => z.StatusPageId == id)
              .Select(z => z.Id)
              .ToListAsync();


        List<StatusMessage> messages = await context.StatusMessages
              .Where(x => pageVirtualServerIDs.Contains(x.VirtualServerId))
              .ToListAsync();
```

However, I would strongly prefer to stick with one query. A slightly more logical way (IMO) to write this would be something like this:

```
    List<StatusMessage> messages = await (
          from statusMessage in context.StatusMessages
          join pvs in context.PageVirtualServer 
          on statusMessage.VirtualServerId = pvs.VirtualServerId
          where pvs.StatusPageId == id
          select statusMessage
    ).ToListAsync();
```